# How can I create a new class variable in 100+ existing classes?

Tags: java, oop, variables, inheritance, design-patterns

I am building a Java program that checks whether or not a car has prior damage by inspecting each part individually. Each part is divided into it's own class.

UML Diagram of a selection of car part classes:
[image]

My problem is that each part already exists and needs a Boolean value called 'damage'. Is there a faster way to assign a damage variable to each class rather than doing it one by one?

Comment: Are all of the car parts subclasses of a `CarPart` class?  If not, they should be.  That way you can just add a boolean instance variable to the top-level class, and all of the subclasses will inherit it.  Good design practices can almost always save you from typing the same thing 100 times over.

Comment: I was just typing up a similar answer. You're still going to need to modify every class if you don't have a `CarPart` super class. But since you're going to anyway, you should really use inheritance in this situation.

Comment: Thanks Charlie! No they are not. That's a great idea. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you Greg! I appreciate the feedback! Very helpful

Answer (score 1):

Can you create an `EnginePartHealth` with an boolean value, `isHealthy`, say, that you can then add to each part that needs it?

Go for composition over inheritance if you can.. seems to be what you're doing already. This will enable your design to be more flexible. Using a parent class with a health indicator in it may also work but tends to be less flexible... it may still work for you though and requires less coding..  you may want to add some intermediate class that acts as a parent to any parts you want to maintain engine health on... saying that if you make `Mirror` a subclass of `CarPart` and it automatically inherits health, you may end up with a mess of parent classes for grouping lots of items that just confuses things beyond comprehension... favour composition over inheritance where possible.

You can then create an interface along the lines of `Healthiness` which will enable you to carry out health related operations on all classes implementing the interface (which you'll store high up in your application somewhere to make measuring health easier - in a list/map depending on how you want to access those parts' health).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can define an interface `Inspectable` with a method `isDamaged()`. Your program can reply on this `Inspectable.isDamaged()` but not the actual `damage` attribute. As you mention there are 100+ classes so car parts may have different forms. You can place business logic in a method and provide flexibility. For a boolean variable, it only has true or false which does not have much variety.

Define another class `CarPart` which implements `Inspectable` and have a private `damage` attribute. It serves an superclass of all car parts in your application. If `CarPart.isDamaged()` do not fit some subclass need, they can override it and implement their own version of `isDamaged()`.

Answer (score 0):

While both options - common parent class and interface implementation will technically work, common parent is more suitable for your case. Interface implementation is mainly to define common behavior, while in your case you need to define common state.